# Arbitrary Union and Intersection of all nonempty finite subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

The question is stated as:
Consider a nonempty set $W$. Let $F$ be the set of all nonempty finite subsets of W. Find $\bigcup_{A \in F}A$ and $\bigcap_{A \in F}A$.

So what i have done: knowing that $(\forall x)(x \in W \Leftrightarrow \{x\} \subseteq W)$, we have that for any $x$ in $W$ the singleton set  $\{x\}$ is also in $F$, thus the union of all these singleton sets is all the elements of $W$, then $\bigcup_{A \in F}A = W$.

For the intersection part i think its possible to have two different results, if we consider $W$ as a singleton like $W=\{a\}$, then $F=\{\{a\}\}$ and in this case $\bigcap_{A \in F}A = \{a\} = W$.
But if we consider $W$ having two or more elements we will have an obvious intersection with disjoint sets and therefore $\bigcap_{A \in F}A = \emptyset$.

My results are correct? and should i did this with less words?

Comment: Seems correct to me...and an appropriate amount of words too!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i still very confuse where to use more words or more math symbols.

Comment: It takes a lot of practice but it helps to read a lot of what other people have written, and also go back and read things you wrote a long time ago. This is a good way to see places where people (including your past self!) use too much or too little notation.

Comment: Yes, the results, and, most importantly, the proofs, are correct.